# SQL injection in LIKE with backslash allowed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Currently, I'm testing some code, and I noticed this:

```
$data = str_replace( array('"', "'") , "", $_GET['input']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM tab WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%$data%'";
```

Now, I have no interest in asking how to make this code safe. I would be interested to know how you could use the backslash (`\\`), or anything else, to cause an SQL injection in real world. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do a critical SQL injection attack on this piece of code. The thing is, that only another apostrophe `'` can break out of the `'%$data%'` part of the WHERE clause, but all apostrophes are removed in the `str_replace`. I'm very curious to know if there are other ways to do it. +1

Comment: @eggyal, in my case it is 'latin1', but I'd be curious to know also for 'utf8'

Comment: I would sugest using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, so it's taking the characterset of your DB connection into account

Comment: @Ronald Swets, I'm not asking that, thanks

Comment: @Laxus what is "your" case?

Comment: @Laxus: Actually, I retract.  I suspect this approach may be safe, but I certainly wouldn't want to rely upon it (it could, for example, mangle the input if an old multibyte character encoding is used).

Comment: @Your Common Sense, I logged on this account when I opened the question without realizing it, now I go ahead with Laxus (sorry)

Comment: @eggyval, I also have the same opinion. But it's crazy to use the word safe in this case! :°D

Answer (score 1):

Although there might be some unicode tricks to insert an ' in $data which isn't a ' in php terms, but is interpreted as an ' by your database (I know this sounds fussy) the first thing I notice about this example is that I'm unable to search for phrases like "it's" or "I'm".

Comment: Just curious, how many answers you are going to write for this question?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: SO permits multiple answers to be posted for [a reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25210).

Comment: unlikely :) there's a related `addslashes` "exploit" that works with GBK db charsets, but that's pretty much it

Answer (score 1):

@Laxus It depends not realy on used encodings, but assumed encodings. If the php code assumes one encoding (which usually isn't UTF-8 because php can't handle multibyte strings by default so it just takes a character for every byte) while the database uses another (for example UTF-8)

The UTF-8 scheme can use mutiple bytes to encode a code point to a character as can be seen on the wikipage http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Codepoints below 127 are stored in a single byte using the following scheme:

0xxx xxxx

where x is the bits of the code point.
If a codepoint is above 127 (ie: more than 7 bits) it uses two bytes:

110x xxxx 10xx xxxx

The ' has a codepoint of 27 (hex) or 10 0111 (binary). Normaly this is stored in a single byte

0 **010**  **0111**

in hex still: 27

A malicious attacker could choose to store this in two bytes  (padded with 0's)

110 **0**  **0000**  10 **10**  **0111**

and in hex: C0 A7

Now php processes this and assumes these two bytes are two separate characters (because it just uses ascii). It tries to replace 27 by nothing, but the string only contains C0 and A7 so no 27 found. However, the database does understand UTF-8 and decodes this code point back to '.

**Possible Injection!!**

These type of encodings are called overlong encodings and arn't really valid utf-8 characters, but it might just slip trough a buggy utf-8 implementation.

Comment: I believe that "Injection succeeded!" statement can be added **only** after the code that demonstrates the vulnerability, not just some speculations on the topic.

Comment: Fine, I'll change it.

Comment: So, you are talking of some imaginary "buggy implementation" that may cause an error. Do you happen to know of any particular one?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem why don't you post just *code* that everyone can run and see?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Every implementation of unicode 3.0 and earlier ;).

Comment: @YourCommonSense: nips, my bad... a tad over-eager, 't was but a typo in my test :s

Answer (score 0):

It's just not possible with current code. Although you can perform a sql injection when there are 2 parameters present, imagine the next piece of code:

```
$data1 = str_replace( array('"', "'") , '', $_GET['input1']);
$data2 = str_replace( array('"', "'") , '', $_GET['input2']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM tab WHERE LOWER(title) = '$data1' AND asd = '$data2';";
```

Now you guess the order of the params (permutations or try/error) and then send a backslash in the first $_GET param, propertly encoded (%5c). You get:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE LOWER(title) = '\' AND asd = '$data2';
```

Title field now must match **"\' AND asd = "** which I doubt happens. As a second $_GET param, you can pass (AND 1=1) -- . The final comment (--) here is important because you have to get rid of the last quote. You finally get:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE LOWER(title) = '\' AND asd = '(AND 1=1) --';
```

Its done. If you want to dump impormation schema you cant still use quotes, so you have to use hex values, the server is completely powned.